# Kendo Listview Navigation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am simply trying to create a link to another html page within a kendo listview.
The list item renders fine and it is clickable, however when i click the link, all it does is append a "#MyPage.html" to the current URL and does not navigate anywhere.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<div data-role="view" id="tabstrip-profile" data-title="My List" data-layout="mobile-tabstrip">
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
    <li>Main Menu
        <ul>
            <li><a href="MyPage.html">Go To My Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to load a new Kendo View inside MyPage.html? if yes, MyPage.html should contain a Kendo view defined. If MyPage.html is just an html file and you wanna display the contents as is, add data-rel="external" to the anchor tag.

```
<a href="MyPage.html" data-rel="external">Go To My Page</a>
```

if you are not able to fix the issue, please post the full contents of MyPage.html here.

[Kendo Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#linking-to-external-pages)